sage X3 webservice connection with mobile app error xml parser exception: XmlParserException: "<" expected at 1:1
When attempting to send a SOAP request to Sage X3 for login from my mobile app, an error message appears: "405 Method not allowed" with an additional XML parser exception: "XmlParserException: '<' expected at 1:1." Could someone provide assistance with resolving this issue?
I've been trying to log in from my Flutter app to Sage X3 using SOAP web services, but instead of logging me in, it continues to return this error.
